# how to ignore backing up certain tables with innobackupex

Tags: database-backups, percona

I am using innobackupex to back up my database but I need to ignore a few tables.
is there an --ignore-tables option? I can't seem to find any examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update (thanks to Shlomi's comment): Percona in XtraBackup 2.3, there's an option `--tables-exclude`

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.3/xtrabackup_bin/xbk_option_reference.html says:

> **--tables-exclude=name**
>
> Filtering by regexp for table names. Operates the same way as xtrabackup --tables, but matched names are excluded from backup. Note that this option has a higher priority than xtrabackup --tables.

---

Before XtraBackup version 2.3, there is no option in xtrabackup or innobackupex to ignore certain tables while backing up the rest.

You could use `--include` and give a regular expression that matches all tables except the ones you want to ignore.

For example, you could put the tables to ignore into a separate database, and then back up all the databases except for that one.

Comment: Since the tiem this was answered, `xtrabackup` added support for table exclusion. Use `--tables-exclude`:

    --tables-exclude=name
      filtering by regexp for table names. Operates the same
      way as --tables, but matched names are excluded from
      backup. Note that this option has a higher priority than
      --tables.

Comment: Thanks, I see it appeared in XB 2.3.